# Can I restrict input to ck editor

Tags: ckeditor

I'm new to ck-editor software and I'd like to ask if it's possible to "restrict" the input of ck-editor in the following manner:

I have an XML document that is being displayed in the browser. It's displayed not as an XML but as text (without the tags). For example I have something like that:

Inner representation:

```
<span type="container" id="_92031310" class="widget container "> 
  <span type="p" class="widget p " id="">text content here...</span>
</span>
```

On-screen:

```
text content here...
```

If I open the ck-editor on this element (container) I see only the text content. When I click the mouse at the end of the content to add new text, it appears between the last ending spans. For example like this:

```
<span type="container" id="_92031310" class="widget container "> 
  <span type="p" class="widget p " id="">text content here...</span>
  new text content here (how to restrict that?)
</span>
```

Instead to be added after the '...' string.

Can this restriction be configured in ck-editor and how?

Comment: I had a different use case. however, the problem is quite similar  where I needed to edit content inside <p> tag. Finally, I had no option other than displaying <html> in text editor and allowed the user to edit the html than text.

Comment: I have already done that and works but it would be more appropriate for the user to make modifications directly to the content without interfere with XML details.